# UCAExc:::3.0.7 unknown token: error in inserting date

Tags: java, jdbc, ucanaccess

I've a table in my .mdb database. I want to insert date in this table. So I wrote this code for this

```
public void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        PreparedStatement state;
        Connection connect;
        DateFormat dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
        Calendar cal=Calendar.getInstance();
        String date=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime());
        System.out.println(date);
        try {
            connect = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:ucanaccess://C:/Users/FTK1187/Desktop/eArchiveMaster.mdb","FTEC198","");
            String sql="INSERT INTO LastUpdated (LastUpdatedDate) VALUES (#"+date+"#)"; 
            state=connect.prepareStatement(sql);
            state.execute();
            state.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
```

And it gives me this error

```
net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessSQLException: UCAExc:::3.0.7 unknown token: 
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareStatement(UcanaccessConnection.java:528)
    at org.solr.InsertLastUpdate.main(InsertLastUpdate.java:27)
    at org.solr.updateServlet.doGet(updateServlet.java:40)
    at org.solr.updateServlet.doPost(updateServlet.java:59)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:661)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:231)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:199)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:493)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:140)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:650)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:87)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:342)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:800)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:806)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1498)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: unknown token: 
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
    at net.ucanaccess.jdbc.UcanaccessConnection.prepareStatement(UcanaccessConnection.java:525)
    ... 27 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: unknown token: 
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserBase.read(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadSimpleValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesValueExpressionPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesPrimary(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesFactor(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesTerm(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadAllTypesCommonValueExpression(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadValueExpressionOrNull(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadValueExpressionWithContext(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.readRow(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDQL.XreadContextuallyTypedTable(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserDML.compileInsertStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compilePart(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.ParserCommand.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.compileStatement(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.StatementManager.compile(Unknown Source)
    at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
    ... 30 more
```

The date format is general date in my database. When I'm doing this

```
System.out.println(date);
```

it gives me what I want but when I want to insert in my database I get an error. I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Please do **not** concatenate values into SQL strings. Use the `PreparedStatement` correctly by using a placeholder `?` and then `PreparedStatement.setDate()` or `setTimestamp()` to pass an instance of `java.sql.Date` or `java.sql.Timestamp`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to use `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar`. To insert a date we can simply use something like

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO LastUpdated (LastUpdatedDate) VALUES (?)";
state = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
state.setDate(1, java.sql.Date.valueOf(LocalDate.now()));
state.execute();
state.close();
```

or, since we are inserting the current date, we can just do

```java
String sql = "INSERT INTO LastUpdated (LastUpdatedDate) VALUES (DATE())";
state = connect.prepareStatement(sql);
state.execute();
state.close();
```